# Why log.Println("does not log into file")?

Tags: go

This is my first attempt to log into files with golang.

```
file, _ := os.Open("logfile")
log.SetOutput(file)
log.Println("foo")
```

these lines build, but are not working. Why?

Comment: You're ignoring errors then ask why your code does not work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why log.Println(“does not log into file”)?

The reason is because you didn't check the file is exist or not form your code.

```
file, _ := os.Open("logfile")
```

you're using `_` and didn't check the error. This is important if you wanted to write something in to file. For example look at this code :

```
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filePath+fileName, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        // if error then you need to create the file first
        err = os.MkdirAll(filePath, os.ModePerm)
    }
```

from above code you can see the error checking using `if err != nil`. if the file is not exist yet then create the file first. using `os.MkdirAll()`.

Comment: It should be `return createLogFile(prefix, filePath, fileName)`. Plus, it would be an infinite loop in case if for some reason the path exists but the file is not accessible (lack of permissions)

Comment: @zerkms ahh I see you're right about that. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

os.Open calls [OpenFile](https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=7374:7411#L236)(name, O_RDONLY, 0). This does not have the flag O_CREATE to create the file if it does not exist. Therefore you need to call OpenFile with the O_CREATE flag. I have commented out the error code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    O_RDONLY int = syscall.O_RDONLY // open the file read-only.
    O_RDWR   int = syscall.O_RDWR   // open the file read-write.
    O_CREATE int = syscall.O_CREAT  // create a new file if none exists.
    O_APPEND int = syscall.O_APPEND // append data to the file when writing.
)

func main() {
    /*f1, err := os.OpenFile("testlogfile1", O_RDONLY, 0) // Equivalent to os.Open("testlogfile1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file1: %v", err)
    }
    // ** error opening file: open testlogfile1: no such file or directory exit status 1 **

    defer f1.Close()

    log.SetOutput(f1)
    log.Println("This is a test for log 1")*/

    f2, err := os.OpenFile("testlogfile2", O_RDWR | O_CREATE | O_APPEND, 0644)
    /* Note that you want:
     * O_RDWR to write to the file
     * O_CREATE to create file if it does not exist
     * O_APPEND to add additional information to existing file */

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file2: %v", err)
    }

    defer f2.Close()

    log.SetOutput(f2)
    log.Println("This is a test for log 2")

}
```

Always check those errors!

Answer (score -1):

```html
file, err := os.Open("file.go") // For read access.
if err != nil {
 // do something
}

// and try to include the file path...
```